AWS Lambda Golang Timeout Issue When Sending Automated Telegram Birthday Messages
So i developed a bot for telegram to send birthday messages.
It worked well for 2 months on EC2 instance
now i want to move it to AWS Lambda and run it once a day
i read some and deployed it but it always give me timeouts
example error
Task timed out after 60.02 seconds

this is the main.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/secretsmanager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"

    tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5"
)

type Secrets struct {
    BotAPIKey        string `json:"BOT_API_KEY"`
    ChatID           string `json:"CHAT_ID"`
    ConfluenceAPIKey string `json:"CONFLUENCE_API_KEY"`
}

func getSecrets() (*Secrets, error) {
    secretName := "HIDDEN"
    region := "eu-west-1"

    config, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion(region))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    svc := secretsmanager.NewFromConfig(config)

    input := &secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{
        SecretId:     aws.String(secretName),
        VersionStage: aws.String("AWSCURRENT"),
    }

    result, err := svc.GetSecretValue(context.TODO(), input)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var secrets Secrets
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(*result.SecretString), &secrets)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &secrets, nil
}

func initializeBot(botAPIKey string) (*tgbotapi.BotAPI, error) {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI(botAPIKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    bot.Debug = true
    fmt.Println("im here")
    return bot, nil
}

func handleRequest() error {
    log.Println("Starting handleRequest")

    secrets, err := getSecrets()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error getting secrets: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    bot, err := initializeBot(secrets.BotAPIKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error initializing bot: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    chatID, err := strconv.ParseInt(secrets.ChatID, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error converting chatID to int64: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    scheduleBirthdayMessages(bot, chatID, secrets.ConfluenceAPIKey)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handleRequest)

}

The functions spreads across multiple files in the project but they all work well,
i think i'm doing something wrong with the handle
also the way i deploy it aws is by building it and zipping it
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o bootstrap
zip lambda-handler.zip bootstrap


If you are deploying large binaries, you can use Lambda Layers to separate the Telegram bot and AWS SDK dependencies to reduce the size of the deployment package.

@liaifat85 it is only 8mb

You can consider using Amazon EventBridge (CloudWatch) to trigger your Lambda function at a specific time each day.

@liaifat85 i know but first i want to make it work :)
it timeouts for a reason i don't understand

Mistakenly configured it for VPC but failed to provide network path out of the VPC? If it doesn't strictly need to be in your VPC then don't put it in a VPC.

@jarmod where do you see the VPC part?
i did put it in vpc but because it is mandatory by our org.
also the EC2 that the app was deployed to was on the same vpc and it all worked great

Timeout is a classic indication of network connectivity issues. The primary cause of that in AWS is being in a VPC but with incorrect routing (e.g. wrong subnet) or lack of outbound path (typically NAT/IGW or lack of VPC Endpoint). If you have NAT and IGW then make sure your Lambda function is configured in a private subnet, not public subnet. If your only outbound request is to an AWS service (Secrets Manager?) then ensure the Lambda function has a route to NAT or a Secrets Manager VPC Endpoint.

@Eladik since you're trying to contact the outside world, and your lambda is hiting the maximum runtime and timing out, it's reasonable to conclude you're running your lambda in a VPC subnet that routes through an internet gateway.  Since lambdas can't have public IPs, they must run in a subnet with a default route throuhg a NAT gateway instead

@Eladik, turn on AWS X-Ray for your Lambda Function

Turn on AWS X-Ray for your Lambda Function.
Check Instrumenting Go code in AWS Lambda documentation.
Once done, invoke your function several times so Traces are recorded.
Go to Lambda Function Monitoring tab, scroll down and look for Traces.
Select one and look for Segments Timeline.
This should give you more details about your code execution.

Thanks, I will look into it tomorrow and Update here

So i turned on X-Ray
it helped me understand that i did not placed the lambda function in the correct subnet.
Now i encountered another bug.
for 3 runs the function succeeded, after that i always get this error
{   "errorMessage": "Post \"https://api.telegram.org/botHidden:Hidden/getMe\": read tcp xxx.xx.xx.x:42578->xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443: read: connection reset by peer",   "errorType": "Error" }
i did not change a single configuration, it just appeared somehow
running it locally works great :)
seem that my function got recognized by telegram and gets aborted every time.
